# Redirects and SEO

Tags: category, redirect, 301-redirect, redirect-url

We have a category that we make available for approximately 2 weeks every 2 months for a presale. Once the presale is finished I redirect the category to another using a custom redirect.

What sort of redirect should I use to best serve google SEO purposes 301 or 302. And if you have the time to provide an explanation that would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you place 301 redirect the old url will be taken off Google index. 
When you enable the url again it takes time to index it. I would recommend you not to place redirects and left the page as it is if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the above answer.

Ignore using redirects if and wherever possible.
But when necessary, implement 301 instead of 302.
301 can be referred as "permanently moved" which is supported by SEO.
302 is like "temporarily moved" & it doesn't support SEO. Generally, it shrinks the page rank.

So, It is safe to use redirection only by 301.

Answer (score 0):

Google is very smart now in days, They using AI to detect and handle On-page SEO elements for the site, Let me come to your answer: The 302 redirect means that the page has been moved temporarily and the other, 301, means that a new page has taken over permanently as per you have mention details in your page its not permanent redirect so I would recommend using 302 and no worry for google SEO.